# Swift: How to create an extension of Dictionary to add one value in the collection

Tags: swift, dictionary, extension-methods

I want to create an extension of `Dictionary` in Swift, to add one method called `prepare(for type: String)`.

What the additional method does, is basically add one more key-value pair to the current dictionary, where `key` is the `type` and the `value` is derived from the `type`.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a `Model` based on Dictionary, the `Model` protocol that you see below is just some boilerplate codes to do some basic data processing like getById, insert, update, delete.

So far, I've tried a few stuff...

---

```
extension Dictionary: Model {
    mutating func prepare(forType type: String) {
        self[type] = findByType(type);
    }

    func findByType(type: String) -> String {
        return "TYPE-" + type;
    }
}
```

> This one will throw an error
>
> `Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' with an index of type 'String'`
>
> on the `self[type] = findByType(type)` line

---

```
extension Dictionary: Model {
    mutating func prepare(forType type: String) {
        self.merge(newDict) { (_, new) in new };
    }
}
```

> this one will throw an error
>
> `Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[_ : _]'`
>
> on the `self.merge` line

---

with the `Model` protocol looking like this.

```
protocol Model {
    func formId() -> String;
    func getById(_ id: String) -> Dictionary<String, Any>?;
    func upsert(_ id: String, withData data: Dictionary<String, Any>);
    func delete(_ id: String);
}
```

Comment: You should post your Model protocol

Comment: This is likely the wrong approach. Do you really mean that absolutely every possible Dictionary is a Model (or even every possible [String:String] is a Model)? For example, if I create a dictionary of book titles to book contents, should that be a Model? Or are there additional things you expect about the strings? (Your `findByType` method seems to have some assumptions about what kinds of keys are valid.) If this is the case, you need a struct that *contains* a Dictionary, not extend Dictionary itself. It's even possible that Model should be a struct rather than a protocol.

Comment: actually, the type is not _always_ going to be `[String: String]`, but it will be `[String: Any]`, but you brought up a good point, maybe I should instead subclass `Dictionary` to be a `Model` instead?

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary` is a generic, the key can be anything which conforms to `Hashable` and the value can be `Any`.

Your extension uses concrete `String` keys and `String` values so you need to add a constraint, and there is another error message *missing argument label 'type:' in call* in the `self[type] =` line.

And remove the trailing semicolons, this is not Objective-C

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == String {
    mutating func prepare(forType type: String) {
        self[type] = findByType(type: type)
    }

    func findByType(type: String) -> String {
        return "TYPE-" + type
    }
}
```